# C++:: Call class method using vector iterator?

Tags: c++, vector, class-method

I have a class called Room, the Room class has setPrice and display function.

I stored room objects in a vector:

```
room.push_back(Room("r001", 1004, 2, "small"));
room.push_back(Room("r002", 1005, 2, "small"));
room.push_back(Room("r003", 2001, 4, "small"));
room.push_back(Room("r004", 2002, 4, "small"));
```

In my main function, i create a display function to display all rooms. Here is my code:

```
void displayRoom()
{
    vector<Room>::iterator it;
    for (it = room.begin(); it != room.end(); ++it) {
         *it.display(); // just trying my luck to see if it works
    }
}
```

But it does not call the Room's display method.

How do I call the Room(class)'s display method (no argument) and setPrice(1 argument) method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dereferencing has higher priority than member access. You could add parens (`(*it).display()`), but you should just use the shortcut that was introduced long long ago (in C) for this: `it->display()`.

Of course the same rule applies for pointers and everything else that can be dereferenced (other iterators, smart pointers, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. Chosen by workable solution and first answerer.

Comment: If there anyway to call specific vector element's function. Like: room[2]->setPrice(200)

Comment: @cpp_noob: `room[2]` gives you something. It it's an object, call the method as you would on any object (`room[2].setPrice(200)`). If that something needs to be dereferenced again, you need to dereference it - again `(*(room[2])).setPrice(200)` or `room[2]->setPrice(200)`.

Answer (score 3):

Try `(*it).display()` or simply `it->display()`.

Answer (score 1):

Iterators are a bit like pointers.  So you want either:

```
it->display();
```

or:

```
(*it).display();
```

Comment: The second is wrong, unless it's a vector of `Room *` (in the example, it isn't - and if it was, the first is wrong instead).

Answer (score 0):

Using Vector, you can also use classic form

```
for(size_t x = 0; x < room.size(); x++) {
    room[x].display(); //for objects
    //room[x]->display(); //for pointers
}
```